# Need only to change links from https to http to access files with no SSL?

Tags: http, ssl, https

I have SSL enabled for subdomain.mydomain.com so I can access files via https://subdomain.mydomain.com. Now please tell me if I'm right.. if I have file somwhere in subdomain.mydomain.com called index.php I can securely access it via:

https://subdomain.mydomain.com/someFolder/index.php

but I can also access it via

http://subdomain.mydomain.com/someFolder/index.php

This time communication won't be encrypted though. So now it comes down to links only if I access files in subdomain.mydomain.com securely or not?

I will have another related question (and many more probably), but will post it as separate topic to keep things clean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's *usually* how it works, but it depends on your specific webserver's setup. For example, you can configure a web server to disallow non-HTTPS traffic completely or you can even serve totally different content between HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the use of the SSL site for non-https URLs. This way people cannot access the pages without encrypting the communication

In the http virtual host, VirtualHost 192.168.0.4:80, put just the line

```
    Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `https:` or `http:` in your URLs controls whether the access is secure or not.